# compiling a java program from another java program errors

Tags: java, web-applications, javac

I have 2 java projects, one of which is a java web. I'm trying to compile and run the java application PoliceCars from my PoliceWeb application.
PoliceCars compiles and runs smoothly on it's own when ran via netbeans.
however, when compiled via PoliceWeb I get more than 50 compilation errors.
I'll post the code and then my quistion.
CompileAndRun.java - within the PoliceWeb:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.nio.file.Paths;

public class CompileAndRun {
    private static String cPath = "/home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java";
    private static String runPath = "/home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars";

/**
 *
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    new CompileAndRun(args[0], args[1], args[2]);
}

public CompileAndRun(String path, String date, String time) throws Exception {
    try {
        comAndRun(" "+ path + " "+ date + " " + time);
    } catch (IOException | InterruptedException ex) {
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public int comAndRun(String param) throws Exception {        
   //compile PoliceCars.java
   Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("javac -cp pc "+cPath);
   // I've tried also:("javac "+cPath) and different variations

    printLines(" P javac stdout:", p.getInputStream());
    //print the compilation errors
    printLines(" P javac stderr:", p.getErrorStream());
    int result = p.waitFor();
    //run PoliceCars
    Process p2 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("chmod u+x "+runPath + param);
    printLines(" stdout:", p2.getInputStream());
    printLines(" stderr:", p2.getErrorStream());
    result = p2.waitFor();

    System.out.println(" exitValue() " + p2.exitValue());
    System.out.println("running result = " +result);
    return result;
}

private static void printLines(String cmd, InputStream ins) throws Exception {
    String line = null;
    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(ins));
    while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(cmd + " " + line);
    }
  }
}
```

PoliceCars.java:

```
package pc;
import com.google.common.collect.HashBiMap;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;
import static java.lang.Math.abs;
import java.nio.charset.Charset;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.nio.file.Paths;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import org.jgrapht.graph.DefaultEdge;

public class PoliceCars {

private static List<List<ConcreteData>> weatherList;
private static List<List<ConcreteData>> roadList;
private static List<List<ConcreteData>> accidentsList;
private static List<List<ConcreteData>> countList;
private static List<List<ConcreteData>> placementList;
private static List<ConcreteData> placedCars;
private static List<List<RoadData>> roadsPlacedOn;
private static RoadGraph rg;
private static pathsForEveryPoliceCar dpc;
private static String userFile;
private static String userDate;
private static String userTime;

/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 * @throws java.io.FileNotFoundException
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException, IOException{

    List<String> countFileNames = new LinkedList<>();
    List<String> weatherFileNames = new LinkedList<>();
    List<String> roadFileNames = new LinkedList<>();
    List<String> accidentsFileNames = new LinkedList<>();
    List<String> placementFileNames = new LinkedList<>();


    List<RoadData> roads = new LinkedList<>();

    List<String> lines = Arrays.asList("The first line", "The second line");
    Path p = Paths.get("f1.txt");
    Files.write(p, lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));


    weatherList = new LinkedList<>();
    roadList = new LinkedList<>();
    accidentsList = new LinkedList<>();
    countList = new LinkedList<>();
    placementList = new LinkedList<>();
    placedCars = new LinkedList<>();
    roadsPlacedOn = new LinkedList<>();
    List<RoadData> allTheRoadsSegments = new LinkedList<>();
    String filePath = RunPy.run("/home/noa/Documents/untitled/HelloWorld.py", "27.01.2015", "08:00");

    lines = Arrays.asList("The first line", "The second line");
    p = Paths.get("the-file-name.txt");
    Files.write(p, lines, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));

    System.out.println("");
}

/**
 * this function is for running the program all day long 
 */
private static void programLoop(List<RoadData> allTheRoadsSegments) throws IOException{
    HourlyStats hs = new HourlyStats(rg, allTheRoadsSegments);
    dpc = new pathsForEveryPoliceCar(rg, allTheRoadsSegments);
    Map <Integer, String> statsForEveryHour = new HashMap<>();
    List<String> placementFileNames = new LinkedList<>();
    List<List<ConcreteData>> placementList1 = new LinkedList<>();
    List<ConcreteData> oldPlacementList = new LinkedList<>();
    placementFileNames.add("data/police_cars_places.csv");

    while(true){
        try {
            LocalDateTime clock = LocalDateTime.now();
            //getting the police cars placement for this hour
            Parser pp = new PoliceCarsCSVParser();
            placementList1 = pp.parseFromFiles(placementFileNames);

            for(List<ConcreteData> pl : placementList1){
                for(ConcreteData pCar : pl){
                    if(((PoliceCarsPlacement)pCar).getPoliceCarPlaced().equals("1") &&
                            ((PoliceCarsPlacement)pCar).getHour().equals(String.valueOf(clock.getHour())))
                        placedCars.add(pCar);

                    if(((PoliceCarsPlacement)pCar).getPoliceCarPlaced().equals("1") &&
                            ((PoliceCarsPlacement)pCar).getHour().equals(String.valueOf(clock.getHour()-1))){
                        oldPlacementList.add(pCar);
                    }


                }
            }

            setroadsPlacesOn();

            //publish the police car placement
            OutputPoliceCars opc = new OutputPoliceCars(roadList, 15 ,
                    clock, 9, 19, roadsPlacedOn);
            SaveToFile sv1 = new SaveToFile("police_cars_places.csv", opc.writeToFile());

            dpc.setPlaces(oldPlacementList, placedCars);
            statsForEveryHour.put(clock.getHour(), hs.getDistancesBEtweenCars(placedCars));

            oldPlacementList = placedCars;
            placedCars.clear();
            if (clock.getHour() == 19)
                break;

            Thread.sleep(45*60*1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(PoliceCars.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }
File file = new File("outputData/Hourly_stats.txt");
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter (file, true);
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(writer);

for (Map.Entry<Integer, String> entry : statsForEveryHour.entrySet()){
    out.print(String.valueOf(entry.getKey()) + ' ');
    out.println(entry.getValue());
}
DistancesforEveryPoliceCar d = new DistancesforEveryPoliceCar(dpc.getPaths(), rg);

}


private static void setroadsPlacesOn(){
    int k = 0, i = 0;
    List<RoadData> roads = new LinkedList<>();

    for(List<ConcreteData> rl : roadList){
        k = 0;
        i += 1;
        System.out.println("i = " + i);
        if(roads.size() > 0){
            roads = new LinkedList<>();
        }

        for(ConcreteData pCar : placedCars){
            for(ConcreteData r : rl){
                if(k > 0 && (((PoliceCarsPlacement)pCar).getRoadNum()).equals(((RoadData)r).getRoadNumber()) && 
                     (((PoliceCarsPlacement)pCar).getRoadSegement()).equals((((RoadData)r).getRoadSegment()) )){
                        roads.add((RoadData) r);
                }
            k += 1;

        }
            roadsPlacedOn.add(roads);
        }

    }
}

public static String getDataOfDate(String date, String time) {
    String str = "";
    for (List<ConcreteData> list : weatherList) {
        for (ConcreteData concreteData : list) {
            if (((WeatherData) concreteData).getDate().equals(date)) {
                if (((WeatherData) concreteData).GetTime().equals(time)) {
                    str = "weather info for given date:\n" + concreteData.GetData();
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    //concat to str rest of data after parsed.
    return str;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param w - sets the weather list according to the user decision
 * Static or dynamic
 */
public void setWeatherList (List<List<ConcreteData>> w){
    weatherList = w;
}

/**
 * 
 * @param rd - RoadData list - to save all the roads segments 
 */
protected static void createGraph(List<RoadData> rd){
    rg = new RoadGraph();
    int i,j;

    for (i = 0; i < roadList.get(0).size(); i++)
        rg.AddVertex((RoadData) roadList.get(0).get(i));
    for (i = 0; i < roadList.get(0).size(); i++){
        RoadData r1 = (RoadData) roadList.get(0).get(i);
        rd.add(r1);
        for (j = 0; j < roadList.get(0).size(); j++){
            if (i != j){
               RoadData r2 = (RoadData) roadList.get(0).get(j);
               if (r1.getFrom().equals(r2.getFrom()) || r1.getTo().equals(r2.getFrom()) 
                       || r1.getFrom().equals(r2.getTo()) || r1.getTo().equals(r2.getTo()))
                   rg.AddeEdge(r1, r2);
            }                    
        }
    }
}

/**
 * returns the time to go between roads in minutes (it goes between the middle
 * of the source to the middle of the target segment
 * @param sourceStart - the km number of the beginning of the segment of the source segment
 * @param sourceEnd - the km number of the end of the segment of the source segment
 * @param targetStart - the km number of the beginning of the segment of the target segment
 * @param TargetEnd - the km number of the end of the segment of the target segment
 * @param sourceSpeed - the source segment speed limit
 * @param targetSpeed - the target segment speed limit
 * @return - the amount of time to drive from the source segment to the target segment
 */
protected String returnMin(String sourceStart, String sourceEnd, String targetStart, String TargetEnd
        ,String sourceSpeed, String targetSpeed){
    float diffSource = (abs(Float.parseFloat(sourceStart) - Float.parseFloat(sourceEnd))/2),
            diffTarget = (abs(Float.parseFloat(targetStart) - Float.parseFloat(TargetEnd))/2);
    float source = Float.parseFloat(sourceSpeed), target = Float.parseFloat(targetSpeed);
    float time = (diffSource/source) + (diffTarget/target);

    int a = (int) Math.round(time*60);
    return Integer.toString(a);
}
}
```

in the package pc I have all the necessary classes.
while compiling PoliceCars.java from PoliceWeb I get the following errors:

```
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:39: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:     private static List<List<ConcreteData>> weatherList;
Info:   P javac stderr:                              ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class ConcreteData
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:40: error: cannot     find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:     private static List<List<ConcreteData>> roadList;
Info:   P javac stderr:                              ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class ConcreteData
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:41: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:     private static List<List<ConcreteData>> accidentsList;
Info:   P javac stderr:                              ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class ConcreteData
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:42: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:     private static List<List<ConcreteData>> countList;
Info:   P javac stderr:                              ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class ConcreteData
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:43: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:     private static List<List<ConcreteData>> placementList;
Info:   P javac stderr:                              ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class ConcreteData
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:44: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:     private static List<ConcreteData> placedCars;
Info:   P javac stderr:                         ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class ConcreteData
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:45: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:     private static List<List<RoadData>> roadsPlacedOn;
Info:   P javac stderr:                              ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class RoadData
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:46: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:     private static RoadGraph rg;
Info:   P javac stderr:                    ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class RoadGraph
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:47: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:     private static pathsForEveryPoliceCar dpc;
Info:   P javac stderr:                    ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class pathsForEveryPoliceCar
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:92: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:     private static void programLoop(List<RoadData> allTheRoadsSegments) throws IOException{
Info:   P javac stderr:                                          ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class RoadData
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:215: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:     public void setWeatherList (List<List<ConcreteData>> w){
Info:   P javac stderr:                                           ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class ConcreteData
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:223: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:     protected static void createGraph(List<RoadData> rd){
Info:   P javac stderr:                                            ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class RoadData
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:65: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:         List<RoadData> roads = new LinkedList<>();
Info:   P javac stderr:              ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class RoadData
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:79: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:         List<RoadData> allTheRoadsSegments = new LinkedList<>();
Info:   P javac stderr:              ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class RoadData
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:80: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:         String filePath = RunPy.run("/home/noa/Documents/untitled/HelloWorld.py", "27.01.2015", "08:00");
Info:   P javac stderr:                           ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   variable RunPy
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:94: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:         HourlyStats hs = new HourlyStats(rg, allTheRoadsSegments);
Info:   P javac stderr:         ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class HourlyStats
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:94: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:                    RoadData r2 = (RoadData) roadList.get(0).get(j);
Info:   P javac stderr:                    ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class RoadData
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: /home/noa/NetBeansProjects/PC/src/pc/PoliceCars.java:234: error: cannot find symbol
Info:   P javac stderr:                    RoadData r2 = (RoadData) roadList.get(0).get(j);
Info:   P javac stderr:                                   ^
Info:   P javac stderr:   symbol:   class RoadData
Info:   P javac stderr:   location: class PoliceCars
Info:   P javac stderr: 55 errors
```

those are part of the 55 errors. I've tried import pc.*; but it didn't help.
any thoughts as to why I get those errors?
how can I compile and run PoliceCars successfully?
and is there a way to compile independently of the OS?